# If object contains null value how to assign empty string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, append

I have an object,

```
data: [
    {
     "name": "aaa",
     "email": null,
     "username": "bbb",
     "age": 56,
     "dob": null,
  },
  {
     "name": "ddd",
     "email": null,
     "username": "ggg",
     "age": 46,
     "dob": null,
  },
]
```

If i append the data like,

```
$.each(data,function(i,e){
  .........
  $(".email").text(e.email);
  .........
})
```

I got an error

```
Cannot read property 'email' of null
```

So, If there is an null value in the object i want to append it as a `empty string`.
How can i make it.

Comment: How does this data throw "*Cannot read property 'email' of null*" error?

Comment: that error is not saying that `e.email` is null, it is saying `e` is null and with that code, that is impossible.

Comment: You are right @epascarello, i missed one record so that caused me an error. thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
$.each(data,function(i,e){
  .........
  $(".email").text(e && e.email ? e.email : '');
  .........
})
```

This will add email if exists, otherwise, an empty string.

Answer (score -1):

In case attribute is null, one can go with -

```
   $.each(data,function(i,e){
     $(".email").text(e.email == null ? "": e.email);
    });
```

In case possibility of null object, one can go with -

```
$.each(data,function(i,e){
  $(".email").text(e != null && e.email ? e.email : "");
  console.log(e != null && e.email ? e.email : "");
});
```

Comment: This will error if email property is not present, as it seems the case on the original question.

Comment: @avcajaraville the error in the question comes from the fact that `e` is `null`, not the `email` property.

Comment: Tried this on Chrome dev tools, it will not give any error even if property is not present in object, please try once on browser.

Comment: What about if there is an object but no email property? `(e&&e.email)||""`

Comment: @Durgesh With `e.email == null ? "": e.email` you only test for null, and it will result in `"undefined"` if the property is missing (or is set to undefined)

Comment: @some in javascript 'undefined == null' this condition is true; as long as I am with '==' and not '===' this should work.. this is related to concept of coercion in javascript.

Comment: @Durgesh #%&¤*, my mistake. That's why I use === instead of ==.